# MSChart HowTo Create a Second CursorX to have multiple Cursor by a second Transparant ChartArea?

Tags: mschart

> **I am try to introduce a Second CursorX at AxisX Primary if this is possible some how?**

I did try to activate a second CursorX at Secondary but that one did not work as expected,
I also readed about Line Annotation and Vertical Line Annotation and created some kind of line but a Second set of CursorX CursorY would be far nicer

I did try to create and as much as empty as possible and Transparant Second ChartArea which i try to overlay on top of the ChartArea1, i noticed InnerPlotPosition and Postion of both ChartArea should stay in track to get a full aligned Overlay, and next the CursorX of second ChartArea should be displayed on top of ChartArea1

This is what i think how it could be done but don't have a clue if it sounda for a good way to create a second CursorX maybe Line Annotation is an easier road to rome

Any help suggestion are welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your chart contains multiple chart areas aligned vertically, below code allows you set CursorX in each chart area:

```
            Dim c1 As New Chart
            '...here code block to build each chart area ...  
            '...then use below sample code to align each chart area vertically:
            'c1.ChartAreas(i).AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical
            'c1.ChartAreas(i).AlignWithChartArea = c1.ChartAreas(0).Name

            'below set horizontal cursor (it is a gold vertical bar in each chart area): 
            For Each area As ChartArea In c1.ChartAreas
                area.CursorX.LineColor = Color.Gold
                area.CursorX.LineWidth = 3
                area.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = True
                area.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True
                area.CursorX.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGoldenrod
            Next
```